# Word2vector using ELMO - Python

Tags: python-3.x

I'm interested in picking up a set of phrases and converting them to pytorch arrays using BERT, is there any code ready for this?

Answer (score 0):

Of course, there are many publicly available code on contextualized word representations.
([BERT](https://github.com/google-research/bert), [ELMO](https://github.com/allenai/allennlp))